# Benefits of using LDAP?

Tags: database, ldap

LDAP is a general purpose database but is an ideal data store for authentication systems. Why is this true?

I was thinking this was true since LDAP is easily scalable and has proven to be stable.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is lightweight, mature, secure, fast and an Open Standard Protocol.

But as always, the devel is in the details.
Many sites on have longer more complete explanations:

- https://ldap.com/why-choose-ldap/
- https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP